# Sonar Issue: Correctness - Call to equals() comparing different types

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, findbugs

I wonder if you've ever encountered this kind of isssue when comparing two Strings or building a Stringbuilder.

> Correctness - Call to equals() comparing different types
>   findbugs : EC_UNRELATED_TYPES
>   This method calls equals(Object) on two references of different class types with no common subclasses. Therefore, the objects being compared are unlikely to be members of the same class at runtime (unless some application classes were not analyzed, or dynamic class loading can occur at runtime). According to the contract of equals(), objects of different classes should always compare as unequal; therefore, according to the contract defined by java.lang.Object.equals(Object), the result of this comparison will always be false at runtime.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<MaterialUsuarioEO>buscar(FiltroMaterialUsuarioDto filtro){
    String vacio="";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Select mu from MaterialUsuarioEO mu where 1=1");

    if (filtro.getMaterial() != null && !vacio.equals(filtro.getMaterial().getId())) {
        sb.append("and upper(mu.material.id) like :id ");
    }
    if (filtro.getUsuario() != null && !vacio.equals(filtro.getUsuario().getNombre())) {
        sb.append("and upper(mu.usuario.nombre) like :nombre ");
    }

    Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString());

    if (filtro.getMaterial() != null && !"".equals(filtro.getMaterial().getId())) {
        q.setParameter("id", "%" + filtro.getMaterial().getId().toUpperCase() + "%");
    }
    if (filtro.getUsuario() != null && !"".equals(filtro.getUsuario().getNombre())) {
        q.setParameter("nombre", "%" + filtro.getUsuario().getNombre().toUpperCase() + "%");
    }

    return q.getResultList();

}
```

BTW I get this using the SonarQube tools. And no, I'm sure It's comparing two String, so I still don't have a clue, not only I can't determine where I'm failing at but also I don't know what the problem is trying to tell me.

I will keep looking in the meanwhile, and if I find it I'll post it, still would thank some more of your approaches, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the filtro.getMaterial().getId() returns a string? filtro.getUsuario().getNombre()))  certainly sounds like it would return an integer rather than a string too.

Comment: No, both of them are Strings, I can assure you that much

Comment: Why do you have unchecked warnings suppressed? Are some generics involved in this code? Please specify exactly the signatures of `getMaterial()`, `getId()`, `getUsuario()` and `getNombre()`. At which line exactly do you see the FindBugs warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of types are these attributes ?

filtro.getUsuario().getNombre()
filtro.getMaterial().getId()

If they're not of type String you shouldn't compare them via equals.
But you could do the following:

`Integer.valueOf(vacio).equals(filtro.getUsuario().getNombre())`

So the String value of vacio is being cast into an Integer and therefore can be checked against another Integer (getNombre()) via equals.

Comment: They're not integers, they are both strings, despite it being called an Id. We're trying to check if inserted values are illegal enought to block their related query.